# How to make the pink boxes

Tags: discussion

In answers to questions here, I keep seeing text enclosed in pink boxes.  I searched in vain for how to format that.  [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460896/is-magnanimous-right-in-this-context) is an example:

[image]

Comment: See *[How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)* in the [help]; quotes are covered as an "advanced" topic on the [Markdown help](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: By the way, you can press an "edit" button under this question, if you want to see the original markdown. You don't have to save your edit, just look around and play with formatting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see those as pink; however, they are **quotations.**

Quotations are indicated in Markdown by prefixing the paragraph with `>`:

`> This is a quotation.`

> This is a quotation.

Immediately-adjacent paragraphs are joined together:

> This is a paragraph.
>
> This is a second paragraph.

It's possible to separate paragraphs you don't actually want to be joined together with a dummy tag like `<//>`.

> This is a paragraph.

> This is an unrelated quote.

You can see more about this if you click **Edit** below, which will show you the source (but please don't commit any changes!) and there's a more comprehensive help in [Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanx much 4 that!

Comment: @Wordster Please vote rather than commenting (this applies to all posts, not just mine!)

Comment: It's closer to pink on some monitors.